# Finding Color of a UIView Object and change the Color

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.5, ios5

[image]Hello Guys actually i have a lot of UIView custom class objects as a subview of a UIViewController class view which is inside a UIScrollView. And i want to check colors of UIView custom class objects. code i use is given below:-

```
    - (void) RectColorCheck:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *subViews = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    subViews = [self.scrollView subviews];
    NSLog(@"array----%@",subViews);

        for (viewCG in subViews) 
        {
            if ([viewCG.backgroundColor isEqual: [UIColor darkGrayColor]])
            {
                [viewCG setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
            }
        }
}
```

but it not works the subview array of viewCG is null.
And the below code which adds the custom class(UIView) objects in viewCG subviews:-

```
for (int i=0; i<[mapDataArr count]; i++)
    {
        X = [[[mapDataArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"X"] intValue];
        Y = [[[mapDataArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Y"] intValue];
        W = [[[mapDataArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"W"] intValue];
        H = [[[mapDataArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"H"] intValue];

        circleVwObj = [[CircleView alloc] init];
        circleVwObj.frame = CGRectMake(X,Y, W, H);
        circleVwObj.tag = i;

        circleVwObj.lbl.frame = CGRectMake(2,2, circleVwObj.frame.size.width, circleVwObj.frame.size.height/2);
        circleVwObj.lbl.text = [[mapDataArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"standId"];
        NSLog(@"lbl text---%@", circleVwObj.lbl.text);
        circleVwObj.lbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
        circleVwObj.lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        circleVwObj.lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        circleVwObj.lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        circleVwObj.lbl.minimumFontSize = 11;
        circleVwObj.lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        circleVwObj.lbl.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

        [self.viewCG addSubview:circleVwObj];
    }
```

Comment: First of all you shouldn't compare colors the way you do. Use `[view.backgroundColor isEqual:[UIColor darkGrayColor]]`. Are you sure that the `subviews` array is empty or nil? Do you see your `CircleView`s when you launch your app?

Comment: @Tobi okey i change the code as you and omz told. and yes the subviews array is nil.yes i see the circleView Object. I am attached a screen shot.

Comment: This does not help with your issue: There is no reason for alloc init as you are assigning a subview array anyway. The newly created array (using alloc) is discarded on the next statment. If you do not ARC then it will even cause a memory leak. Just assign [self.scrollView subviews] and you are fine.

Comment: Are you really just searching for direct subviews of the scroll view? Or do you need to include subviews of subviews too? (because you don't).

Comment: @HermannKlecker ScrollView have a only one Subview which is viewCG. And i am looking for subviews of viewCG. if i directly using [self.viewCG subViews] that also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `subviews` array is `nil`, it is very likely that `self.viewCG` is `nil` as well and hasn't been initialized.

Also, you should use `isEqual:` to compare colors. The `==` operator just compares pointer identity (which might actually give you the expected result in this particular case, but it's likely to break).

Comment: Did you draw the reference correctly within interface builder?

Comment: @HermannKlecker yes i references it correctly. First files owner View reference to scrollView then i add the a UIView object viewCG.